# how to fetch distribution or OS name in kernel module

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Grabing the distribution name (i.e **Ubuntu, Red Hat Enterprise Linux**) is very easy through command line for example - one can fetch the information from `/proc/version` or `lsb_release -a` or `uname -a` or `/etc/*-release` but my problem is different. I want to fetch distribution name in kernel module in order to enable features on the bases of OS name.

I tried below module. Unfortunately, it didn't work as expected. I want OS name such as Ubuntu, Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/utsname.h>

#define current get_current()

static int __init dummy_ModInit(void)
{
    int retVal;

    pr_info("module init\n");
    pr_info("utsname - %s\n",utsname());
    pr_info("current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name - %s\n", &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name);
    pr_info("current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.release - %s\n", &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.release);
    pr_info("current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.version - %s\n", &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.version);
    pr_info("current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.machine - %s\n", &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.machine);
    pr_info("current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.domainname - %s\n", &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.domainname);
    pr_info("current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.nodename - %s\n", &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.nodename);
    pr_info("current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.sysname - %s\n", &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.sysname);

    return retVal;
}

static void __exit dummy_ModExit(void)
{
        pr_info("module exist\n");
}


module_init(dummy_ModInit);
module_exit(dummy_ModExit);

MODULE_VERSION("1.0.1.1" );
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("fetching kernel version and OSname");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

**Output on redhat machine:**

```
[5254795.119390] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name - Linux
[5254795.119492] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.release - 4.18.0-372.26.1.el8_6.x86_64
[5254795.119597] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.version - #1 SMP Sat Aug 27 02:44:20 EDT 2022
[5254795.119709] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.machine - x86_64
[5254795.119822] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.domainname - (none)
[5254795.119936] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.nodename - shaslinux
[5254795.120053] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.sysname - Linux
```

**Output on ubuntu machine:**

```
[1075545.219864] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name - Linux
[1075545.219865] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.release - 4.15.0-142-generic
[1075545.219865] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.version - #146~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 09:27:15 UTC 2021
[1075545.219865] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.machine - x86_64
[1075545.219866] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.domainname - (none)
[1075545.219866] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.nodename - shashank-linux
[1075545.219867] &current->nsproxy->uts_ns->name.sysname - Linux
```

Is there any way that we can read information in `/proc/version` by using procfs kernel api's.

Any other method such as `call_usermodehelper()`. I mean execute linux command in a .c or .sh file, trigger it from kernel module and runs in usermode. By using this, it will execute a program and returns success or failure. Saving results is the question here.

Appreciating any help in advance.

Comment: This is impossible (no, of course with an **ugly dirty hack** technically it's possible). The kernel doesn't and should not know about the upper layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to tell between 2 specific distributions like redhat and ubuntu, the `utsname` function gives you enough info to tell them apart (mostly the `release` member.)

However, OS specific features are usually enabled according to a kernel version number and not by a distribution name because there isn't much difference between the kernel versions that some distributions use.

Can you be more specific about the features you want to enable so we can find an optimal solution?

Comment: yes you are right but representation of kernel version in redhat is different as compared to ubuntu. So, conditions on kernel version are not working as expected.

Comment: for example - In bash , we can fetch version and can compare like this. VERSION=`cat /proc/version` 
if [[ $VERSION = *"Red Hat"* ]]; then .... fi. Similar thing I want to do in kernel module.

Comment: `/proc/version` is implemented here - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/proc/version.c so if you were going to rely on it than you can use the same logic on the strings returned by `utsname()`

Comment: The example I have shared above clearly showing that uts structure doesn't hold OS names.

Comment: On the Redhat machine the `release` member has "el8" (Indicates RHEL kernel) and on the Ubuntu machine the `version` member has "ubuntu" in it. not very indicative, but clearly tells them apart. If you`ll specify what exact distributions you want to tell apart and what you wish to do with this information maybe I can come up with a more elegant solution...